# Performance of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have learnt neo4j can traverse 1 million records in just 2.7 seconds or in lesser time.I am creating a website which use ajax for lookup words entered by user against oxford dictionary(present in server side) which itself contains 1 million words. 
Thus, geting suggestion in 2.7 seconds for every letter user enter is very slow.
Can any one suggest me , how should i tackle this problem ?
I hope I am clear with my question.

P.S. Consider every word in dictionary as one node

Comment: Perhaps you're using / wanting to use Neo4j wrong .. it's likely not advisable to build an autocomplete field that uses a graph of a million letters .. (Also note those numbers are quotes for *traversals*, not total *nodes*.)

Comment: ok fine , if instead of words in dictionary , say I have million users where each node refer to one user which have username . Can't I use Neo4j for this purpose because even in this scenraio I have to match new username with already existing username ,so that username remain unique.

Comment: For auto-completion you would usually use a kv-store or search engine like solr. Neo4j excels when you want to traverse a network from a local starting point (graph local search). But you can combine Neo4j with other NOSQL databases, as people usually do.

Comment: Ok , I am getting bit confuse, so i should not use Neo4j at all for autocomplete kind of thing ??

Answer (score 0):

Both Solr and Neo4j indexes use Lucene, so why not use Neo4j indexing for autocomplete?

Comment: Because Neo4j uses lucene transactionally. And solr does a lot of optimizations on top of it.